# Using laravel session variable in vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm new in vue Js, when working only with blade im used to do that:

{{ Auth::user()->name }}

How can i do that in blade component ?

thanks.

Comment: use api to get auth user

Comment: after that can i store the response at the session variable?

Comment: no vuex store or local storage

Answer (score 0):

use Vue's props to be able to pass attributes to Vue's components through markup.

```
<auth-details :auth-name="{{ Auth::user()->name }}">
</auth-details>
```

In your vue component,

```
Vue.component('auth-details', {
    props: ['authName'],
});
```

You can access it using `this.authName`.

**Note :** In HTML you need to write attribute name in kebab-case while in Vue side you write it as camelCase.

Comment: @wawingiSebastiao could you atleast inform & if possible accept the answer(clicking on tick), if it worked for you or not.

Comment: can you accept the answer if above answer helped or edit the above answer so that I & others can know what you changed

Comment: im not able yet to accept, cause i've insuficient reputations.

Comment: I solved the problem doing my header as component:

<span class="pro-user-name ml-1">
        {{nome}}
 </span>


                this.$axios.get('auth/pegaUtilizador')
                .then(function (response) {
                    if(response.status==200){
                        self.nome = response.data.name;                   
                    }else{
                        alert("Error ");
                    }
                }